# apply plugin in gradle

Tags: for-loop, gradle, plugins, groovy

I have a quick question on how to formulate my logic to apply custom parameters in my gradle build file.

I want to apply my plugin with the given parameters for each file in a specified directory location.

How might I accomplish this?

UPDATED
build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'quick.plugin'



task applyPluginXMLOne(type: com.nav.QuickFixTask){
        quickfixPlugin.dictFile = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/custom.xml")
        quickfixPlugin.decimal = true
        quickfixPlugin.outputDirectory = file("${buildDir}/generated/")
        quickfixPlugin.schemaDirectory = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/quickfix/generated")
    }

task applyPluginXMLTwo(type: com.nav.QuickFixTask){
        quickfixPlugin.dictFile = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/custom2.xml")
        quickfixPlugin.decimal = true
        quickfixPlugin.outputDirectory = file("${buildDir}/generated/")
        quickfixPlugin.schemaDirectory = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/quickfix/codegen")
    }
applyPluginXMLTwo.mustRunAfter applyPluginXMLOne
```

The result when I run `$ gradle applyPluginXMLOne applyPluginXMLTwo`
:

```
This is my output dictFile C:\dev\src\main\resources\custom2.xml
This is my output outputDirectory C:\dev\build\generated
This is my output orderedFields false
This is my output decimal true
:applyPluginXMLTwo

This is my output dictFile C:\dev\src\main\resources\custom2.xml
This is my output outputDirectory C:\dev\build\generated
This is my output orderedFields false
This is my output decimal true

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Total time: 2.299 secs

Comment: You're overwriting the values such as `dictFile` each time round the loop, so you only end up with the last value...  Is this your plugin? You need to change it to work with a list of settings

Comment: Or dynamically create a task for each file in your resources

Comment: I've done as you said @tim_yates...But the issue I'm seeing is still there

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply the plugin one after the other I needed to add a `build.finalizedBy(task1,task2) portion as shown below.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'quick.plugin'



task applyPluginXMLOne(type: com.nav.QuickFixTask){
        quickfixPlugin.dictFile = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/custom.xml")
        quickfixPlugin.decimal = true
        quickfixPlugin.outputDirectory = file("${buildDir}/generated/")
        quickfixPlugin.schemaDirectory = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/quickfix/generated")
    }

task applyPluginXMLOne(type: com.nav.QuickFixTask){
        quickfixPlugin.dictFile = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/custom2.xml")
        quickfixPlugin.decimal = true
        quickfixPlugin.outputDirectory = file("${buildDir}/generated/")
        quickfixPlugin.schemaDirectory = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/quickfix/codegen")
    }
build.finalizedBy(applyPluginXMLOne,applyPluginXMLOne)
```